# Yet another React + Typescript conditional props question

Tags: reactjs, typescript, discriminated-union

Pretty new to Typescript. I'm trying to make a Button component that builds a className string based on two props: `variant` and `color`. Using those values it will look up a className string on an object like the following:

```
const config = {
  primary: {
    blue: '...',
    green: '...',
  },
  secondary: {
    blue: '...',
    green: '...',
  },
  tertiary: {
    blue: '...',
  },
}
```

Here's where I've ended up on the Button component:

```
type Variant = keyof typeof config

type VariantButton<T extends Variant> = {
  variant?: T
  color?: T extends Variant ? keyof typeof config[T] : never
}

type Props =
  | VariantButton<'primary'>
  | VariantButton<'secondary'>
  | VariantButton<'tertiary'>

const Button: React.FC<Props> = ({
  variant = 'primary',
  color = 'blue',
  ...rest
}) => {
  const className = config[variant]?.[color] // TYPESCRIPT ERROR HERE

  return (
    <button
      {...rest}
      className={className}
    />
  )
}
```

The error is telling me that property `green` does not exist on type `{ blue: '...' }`, which is true of course, but how do I get typescript to treat the variant/color combinations separately so that it only expects color properties from the passed variant?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChS0IA7AZ3kqs2AHM4BeOAb1LjjClAooATwBcXHrzgAjADYBXJOPwA6NfgA0k3syJIqytSs2SAvlt40kDACZCxEqTIVKCRk091J9h9RbjmkjBIsMD24txOcoq%20xv6BpuQwwmBIcABqQmFU8BwA1kjCEJhwyanFcAxMzEkpaZkCKDkAQvIwMNQAPAAqcEgAHsFUNjQZWU0wAHzsjnAAbuM5APzi3ZKUstArcL0DQyNjjTlwS3AFRSVlSBVVLADa3QC6cOJUSHMhpImkV3AACjgwKM2JIAD6HbIwVrtLr4fiCET4SZgiETaEdKidfBWWz2JEohqQ9Gw4KhPHIijUOhwYkGRDEGAqABiAGFOgCIEDphwABSReaLXIEeEgPH%20DbQGb4aJIDxwIxEOhfACU7Gm-IY1LQshQNBoADkUCA0hxbsw7gsjjBHksVHcJVBngB6J07ACafwAogBlFkIACSf16noQCAA8gg4AAJEOe8i8IgweRQKhwHnaOCdaRtDEZ3icBVIOiJJy8bW6g1GpBsTjlvWG40lqRO5G8ZVfcgDSCwOA2JCYFDyWTwWmkIA)